# iText 7 - Parsing exception in PdfReader constructor closes the input stream unexpectedly

Tags: itext7

I'm facing an issue after upgrading to latest version of iText for .NET (7.1.15 -> 7.1.16).

Please see example code below:

```
Stream pdfStream = GetPdfStream(...);

try
{
    IRandomAccessSource randomAccessSource = new RandomAccessSourceFactory().CreateSource(pdfStream);
    ReaderProperties readerProperties = new ReaderProperties
    {
        // ...
    };

    using (var pdfReader = new PdfReader(randomAccessSource, readerProperties))
    {
        pdfReader.SetCloseStream(false);

        // do things with pdfReader
    }
}
catch
{
    // ...
}

// reuse pdfStream somewhere else
```

In this situation if the file can not be parsed I'm getting the exception (expected):

```
iText.IO.IOException: PDF header not found.
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader.GetOffsetTokeniser(IRandomAccessSource byteSource)
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader..ctor(IRandomAccessSource byteSource, ReaderProperties properties)
```

But as an unexpected side effect it also closes the input Stream, which wasn't happening in the previous version (7.1.15). Because the exception happens in PdfReader constructor it also can not yet reach pdfReader.SetCloseStream.

Is there any way to prevent PdfReader from closing the externally provided input stream? Or any chance of a new constructor API that would take 'leaveOpen' parameter [like .NET StreamReader does](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_IO_StreamReader__ctor_System_IO_Stream_System_Text_Encoding_System_Boolean_System_Int32_System_Boolean_).

Comment: Consider wrapping your `Stream` into a stream instance that forwards everything except the `close` call to the wrapped stream.

Comment: Hi @mkl, thanks, that is the last resort option, but it seems more of hack. I'm looking for way to do it via iText classes API, maybe something similar to the one of StreamReader with leaveOpen parameter in constructor if that's possible.

Comment: Are you sure your example code is representative? I could understand that that issue happened if `pdfStream` was declared a `FileStream`; but in your case it is declared a generic `Stream`, and in that case the problem should not occur.

Comment: Hi @mkl. I think the bigger picture here is that when `PdfReader` constructor is called, we want predictability on what it will do with what we pass to it, including unhappy path when the constructor fails. It should be either `do not touch my stuff` or `I'll tell you what to do with my stuff`. When we pass the file path, the expected behaviour is that file will not stay locked (i.e. `do not touch my stuff`). When we pass a stream, the expected behaviour is that stream will be closed, but we can override that in the constructor (i.e. `I'll tell you what to do with my stuff`).

Comment: Yes, it is already clear that the behavior is unwanted. I was in the next step, finding out under which circumstances that behavior occurs. And in that context, after viewing the sources, i was surprised that your code as is would show it.

Comment: Hi @mkl. Yes I can confirm that what you're saying is correct - to observe the described behaviour `pdfStream` must be declared as `FileStream`, not just `Stream`.

Comment: OK. Then i understand why and how the issue arises. Would not declaring it a `FileStream` be an option for you as a work-around?

Comment: Hi @mkl. Yes we can work around our specific issue. The reason we raised this is because we would like to see iText improve (or to be shown that we're missing smth). In v7.1.15 `PdfReader` constructor taking a file path was locking the file if it was failing. v7.1.16 fixed it, but now constructor taking a stream closes the stream if it fails. It's a good improvement, but could be improved further if controlling what to do with the underlying stream was via an optional param to the constructor rather than a method on the constructed instance.

Comment: Thank you Andrew for clarifying the situation and thank you @mkl for looking into it.

Comment: In my eyes the preferred (default?) behavior would be that streams given from outside were left open while streams created by itext itself were closed. The change you observed seems to have been a result of enforcing the latter in an overeager attempt.

Comment: Hi @mkl. `In my eyes the preferred behavior would be that streams given from outside were left open while streams created by itext itself were closed` - I absolutely agree! This is not the behaviour for many .Net classes, which by default close the input stream unless told otherwise, but if iText behaved like you said that would be great. We wrote a wrapper DLL for our internal needs, that takes either file path or stream, and it behaves exactly like you described. Unfortunately the change in v7.1.16 broke it.

Comment: Hi @mkl. Can you pls let us know whether/when the behaviour you described might be implemented?

Comment: I'm not an iText employee, let alone the project lead, so I cannot tell, I simply don't know. You might want to address their support.

Comment: @Andrew stay tuned for the updates, this issue is being worked on

Comment: Thanks @AlexeySubach. When should I check back? Couple of weeks, couple of months?

Comment: Hi @mkl. I actually did think you worked for iText. Their support page says to ask questions on StackOverflow, and you answer a lot of iText-related questions here...

Comment: @Andrew To a small degree i do some freelance consulting there but I'm neither an employee at nor full time working for itext.

Comment: If snapshot version is okay, you can check in a couple of weeks. If you are looking for a release version you will have to wait a couple of months

Comment: It appears that that bug is fixed and merged into 7.1.17 and 7.2.0 versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is fixed in `7.2.0-SNAPSHOT` and `7.1.17-SNAPSHOT` versions.
You can fetch those versions from [iText Artifactory](https://repo.itextsupport.com/) using the following Maven configuration:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>itext-snapshot</id>
    <name>iText Repository - snapshots</name>
    <url>https://repo.itextsupport.com/snapshot</url>
  </repository>
<repositories>
```

Beware that `7.2.0-SNAPSHOT` version contains breaking changes compared to `7.1.16-SNAPSHOT` since 7.2.x line is considered a major upgrade compared to 7.1.x line.

Comment: Alexey Subach do you know when 7.1.17 will be available as stable release? On a different note, I can see in your profile that you're from Minsk - so am I! Though now live in Sydney.

Comment: @Andrew nice! `7.1.17` is going to be released at the end of October. `7.2.0` will likely be released earlier and I recommend switching to `7.2` line - the switch going to be smooth I believe

Comment: Thanks @Alexey, will wait for whichever appears first on GitHub.

Comment: Hi @Alexey, I just tested `v 7.2.0` and it passed all test for not closing input streams and not locking input files! Thanks.